# how to extract a text from a string excel formula not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to extract the Id, the release.. etc, and the search function is not working :(

so I need the formula to look for the release and get the characters after it and before the comma, so on

here is the value of the 2 rows, and as you can see they're in a random arrangement

This whats exactly in the cell values including the {}

{"id":"C0001","brand":"BMW","price":"21868,41 $","release":"2018","name":"BMW 2 Series","type":"COUPES"}

'''[image]

Comment: It would be helpful, if you would post the contents of the image as text, and the order of the desired columns also as text.

Comment: Sorry about this whats in the pic is the Below and the columns are (id, brand, etc)

{"id":"C0001","brand":"BMW","price":"21868,41 $","release":"2018","name":"BMW 2 Series","type":"COUPES"}

Comment: it's not very helpful that the price has a comma

Comment: do it in 3 steps, first search (function SEARCH) for id, brand, etc and store it in a cell, then search for the next " which in excel you have to use """" then use the function PART

Comment: @OlimilOops sorry but I didnt understand what you mean as I have tried to use SEARCH and its not working.     Thing is i need to get whats between the double quotation after the word “brand” for example on the brand column and so on so it should be differrent formulas each one searching for different word

Comment: excel has different function-names in different languages of excel in german it's SUCHEN (=SERACH in engl I guess) and TEIL (=PART in engl I guess) maybe the function names are different

Answer (score 2):

Put the column headers in B1:G1.

Put your String in A2/.

Put this in B2 and copy over:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$2,"{""",""),"""}",""),""",""",""":"""),""":""","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[preceding::*[1]='"&B$1&"']")
```

[image]

Comment: what version of excel is needed?

Comment: OK I've found it, in german version it's =XMLFILTERN()

Answer (score 0):

let's assume: A2 contains your string, A3 the next string etc..
then
b1 contains the string: id
e1 contains the string: brand
h1 contains the string: price
k1 contains the string: release
n1 contains the string: name
r1 contains the string: type

cell b2 contains: =SEARCH(B$1; $A2)+LENGTH(B$1)+3
cell c2 contains: =SEARCH(""""; $A2; B2)
cell d2 contains: =MID($A2;B2;C2-B2)

cell e2 contains: =SEARCH(E$1; $A2)+LENGTH(E$1)+3
cell f2 contains: =SEARCH("""";$A2;E2)
cell g2 contains: =MID($A2;E2;F2-E2)

and so on . . .

Comment: But they are not in a consistent sequence in the string

Comment: that doesn't matter

Comment: you can download the excel workbook from here http://www.activevb.de/cgi-bin/upload/download.pl?id=3838

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using `Power Query`, available in Excel 2010+

- each of your lines is a valid `json`
- Load the worksheet range into PQ with `Data/Get&Transform/From Table/Range`
- From the PQ UI, you can

  - Add Custom Column and Name it `json`:

    ```
     Formula: =Json.Document([Column1])
    ```
  - Add another custom column

    ```
    Formula: =Table.FromRecords({[json]})
    ```

    - Expand the resultant column of tables
    - Remove the unnecessary columns

**M Code**

```
//you may need to change the table name in the second line of code

let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table12"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "json", each Json.Document([Column1])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", each Table.FromRecords({[json]})),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Custom", {"id", "brand", "price", "release", "name", "type"}, {"id", "brand", "price", "release", "name", "type"}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{"json"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```

[image]

*note that the columns will match up properly and, in PQ, you'll be able to set your desired order*

[image]